# Importing module from package raises ModuleNotFoundError for subpackages

Tags: python-import, python-packaging

I'm trying to create a package (that includes several subpackages) for reuse and distribution. The plan is to provide a CLI entry point to allow easy launch. After building the package and installing it in a virtualenv, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` for imports from the subpackages included in the main package.

I think this has something to do with setting the right paths in `__init__.py`, but having read multiple examples on the web, I'm still rather confused as to why anything should go in `__init__py` and what that something is.

The package is built so that the package name (and thus folder created in `site-packages`) is the same as the root in the directory structure below.

The directory structure is (simplified and with names changed):

```
mypackage
|- __init__.py
|- entrypoint.py
|- subpackage1
|-- __init__.py
|-- module1.py
|- subpackage2
|-- __init__.py
|-- module2.py
```

**Note** that all the `__init__.py` are empty

And `entrypoint.py` is:

```
from subpackage1.module1 import foo
from subpackage2.module2 import baz

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

In my `pyproject.toml`, I define:

```
\[project.scripts\]
mypackage-cli = "maypackage:entrypoint"
```

After installing with pip, I run (in a virtualenv where I `pip install`ed the package):

```
(myvenv) me@mymachine ~ % mypackage-cli
```

But I get:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named subpackage1`

Two things to note:

- When running source locally, I have no issues
- If I edit the files in `site-packages` to have `from mypackage.subpackage1.module1 import foo` I don't get the error anymore when running the installed package, but then when trying to run the same modified imports (i.e. changing to `import mypackage.subpackage1.module1`) locally in my dev env, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`

What's the correct way to get the imports to work when packaged and when running locally in my dev env?

Thanks!

Comment: Your "top-level importable package" seems to be `mypackage` so all your import statements should start from there. For example `from mypackage.subpackage1.module1 import foo`. -- To avoid confusion between "local" and "installed" (in `site-packages`), you should use the so-called "`src`-layout" for your project's directory structure, in combination with the "editable" installation.

Comment: You're right, @sinoroc: to solve this issue, I took another look at both the directory structure and working with `pip install -e`. I followed the conventions there, changed the imports to start from the project root directory, and everything works as it should now.

Answer (score 0):

Your "top-level importable package" seems to be `mypackage` so all your import statements should start from there. For example `from mypackage.subpackage1.module1 import foo`.

In order to avoid confusion between "local" and "installed" (in `site-packages`), I recommend you to use the so-called "`src`-layout" for this project's directory structure. In combination with the "editable" installation, it is very convenient to work with.